# Zend Framework 2 TableGateway getAdapter needs Interface

Tags: php, zend-framework2, adapter

Hi I am new to Zend Framework 2
and I am having a problem with this line of code:

```
$sql = new Sql($this->tableGateway->getAdapter());
```

If I test this using Phpunit I get the error

```
Argument 1 passed to Zend\Db\Sql\Sql::__construct() must implement interface 
Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend2
```

Comment: This error tells you that $this->tableGateway->getAdapter() returns null instead of a Db adapter. Which means that you first need to set the DB Adapter in the tableGateway Object that is referred by in $this->tableGatway. Provide us with some more information about how you prepare the db adapter from the service manager and may be we can provide you with a solution to set the adapter in the tableGateway.

Comment: I problem is fixed now, I did not property put the variables in my config. :)

Comment: That is good. It will be good if you mark this question as closed. Take care

Answer (score 0):

Check if adapter is set.

`var_dump(get_class($this->tableGateway->getAdapter()));`

Also you how do you declare `$this->tableGateway` ?

Comment: this has been fixed, $this->tableGateway is from a ServiceManager.